# I need to execute batch file from maven which will take 2 parameters and which should be passed from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I need to execute batch file from maven which will take 2 parameters which should be passed from pom file . I am able to execute the batch file but not able to set the parameters. 
Please let me know how can i set the parameters of batch file

I am writting the below code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>runbatchfile</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <executable>cmd</executable>
        <workingDirectory></workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
            <argument>/C</argument>
            <argument>D:\ITAS_TOI\toi20161207T072319Z\toi\ITAS.bat</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

**Edit** : From comments by OP below:

I tried the below code but its giving me following error:

> The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec are missing or invalid

```
<configuration>
  <tasks>
    <exec dir="D:\ITAS_TOI\toi-20161207T072319Z\toi" executable="D:\ITAS_TOI\toi-20161207T072319Z\toi\ITAS‌​.bat" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="$testingDevice $executedon" />
    </exec>
  </tasks>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried the below code but its giving me following error "The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec are missing or invalid"
<configuration>
     <tasks>
      <exec  dir="D:\ITAS_TOI\toi-20161207T072319Z\toi"
       executable="D:\ITAS_TOI\toi-20161207T072319Z\toi\ITAS.bat"
       failonerror="true">
       <arg line="$testingDevice $executedon" />
      </exec>
     </tasks>
    </configuration>

Comment: did you try the solution suggested, please revert back with what was the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the arguments as follows in the `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <argument1></argument1>
    <argument2></argument2>
</properties>
```

....

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>runbatchfile</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
         <executable>cmd</executable>
         <workingDirectory></workingDirectory>
         <arguments>
            <argument>${argument1}</argument>
            <argument>${argument2}</argument>
            <!--you can rename accordinlgy-->
         </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then on command line execute them as follows :

```
mvn exec:java -Dargument1=/C -Dargument2=D:\ITAS_TOI\toi-20161207T072319Z\toi\ITAS‌​.bat
```